# Generating a 2D array of numbers nested in a dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, tree, nested

I have a dictionary containing some keys as numbers. Each key has a set of values which contain numbers 'nested' within that particular key (this data has been pulled from a database).

Some examples:

- 825 has 838 within it, and within 838 is 2941, and within 2941 is 556. So 4 nested levels.
- 825 has 27 in it, which is only one nested level.
- 23 is nested inside 838 (2 nested levels) but within 23 there is 66, so 3 nested levels.

example structure:

```
dictionary {
    825 : [838, 27],
    838 : [2941, 23],
    2941 : [556, 612],
    23 : [66]
}
```

I have written some code which can get the numbers nested in other numbers, as one of the requirements is to get how 'deep' the nesting goes.

```
// example: call function with key: 825
public int getDepth(int number, Dictionary<int, List<int>> nestedNumbers, int depth)
{
    // 825 is in nestedNumbers
    if (nestedNumbers.Keys.Contains(number))
    {
        // foreach number in 825 [838, 27]
        foreach (var currentNumber in nestedNumbers[number])
        {
            // depth is now level 2
            depth++;
            // call the function again but with 838, which will now get nested groups in 838 [2941, 23]
            return getDepth(currentNumber, nestedNumbers, depth);
        }
    }
    return depth;
}
```

I need to make a list  of lists (or a list of arrays) which contain all the nested levels, like this:

```
lvl1  lvl2  lvl3  lvl4
[[825, 838, 2941, 556],
[825, 27],   
[825, 838, 23, 66],
[825, 838, 2941, 612]]  <-- e.g. 612 is in 2941, 2941 is in 838, 838 is in 825
```

But I'm not sure how to go about it based on the function I have already written. Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is there a typo?  Your function is named `getDepth()` but you call `GetDepth` in the method.  Is that a different method or a typo?

Comment: Your `depth` computation is inaccurate. Don't increment inside of the loop--that adds depth for the size of the list. Call `getDepth(currentGroup, nestedNumbers, depth + 1);`. Additionally, take the max of these `getDepth` calls in cases where there may be multiple routes to a leaf.

Comment: sorry @maccettura it's recursive and I forgot to add the return on getDepth

Comment: ah yeah I see what you mean, it's always going to be one depth level behind

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your requested output. What is being represented, exactly? Why is `[838, 2941, 556]` not included but `[838, 23, 66]` is? How about `[23, 66]`?

Comment: your right my output was not very clear. I have updated it. I think this is more clear now as to what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) problem. In [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) terminology, we want all paths from the root of the tree to leaves, or nodes that have no children. Here is a visualization of your tree:

```
       825
      /   \
     838   27
    /  \
  2941  23 
  /  \   \
556  612  66
```

This traversal can be accomplished using a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) or [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) data structure (recursion is stack-based) to perform the traversal. I opted to use a queue in this example.

The traversal portion involves enqueueing the current node's children and using a dictionary to keep track of each child's parent, then dequeueing children one by one and repeating the process until a leaf node is reached. Once such a node is discovered, the path back to the root can be built by travelling back up to the tree until the root is reached and adding the path onto the result list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> tree = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>()
        {
            {825, new List<int> {838, 27}},
            {838, new List<int> {2941, 23}},
            {2941, new List<int> {556, 612}},
            {23, new List<int> {66}},
        };

        foreach (var row in FindPathsToLeaves(825, tree))
        {
            foreach (var cell in row) 
            {
                Console.Write(cell + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static List<List<int>> FindPathsToLeaves(int root, Dictionary<int, List<int>> tree)
    {
        List<List<int>> paths = new List<List<int>>();
        Dictionary<int, int> parent = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        parent[root] = -1;
        Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
        q.Enqueue(root);

        while (q.Count > 0) 
        {
            int current = q.Dequeue();

            if (tree.ContainsKey(current))
            {
                foreach (int n in tree[current])
                {
                    parent[n] = current;
                    q.Enqueue(n);
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                List<int> path = new List<int>();

                while (parent.ContainsKey(current))
                {
                    path.Insert(0, current);
                    current = parent[current];
                }

                paths.Add(path);
            }
        }

        return paths;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
825 27 
825 838 2941 556 
825 838 2941 612 
825 838 23 66
```